# how to use rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to roll one version back, But I don't know the current VERSION, Is there a command to check it?

Comment: Do you need more information in order to accept an answer? Are you still having problems?

Comment: sorry dude, I was too excited to try each solution out, and forget came back to accept answer

Comment: no problem ^^ I was just wondering if I had to add anything to my answer

Comment: how to add @yozloy in the front of your comment, it's a quote function or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, it's worth taking the time to read the [Rails Guide regarding migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). Then regarding your specific question:

... to roll back one version:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

... to see the current version:

```
rake db:version
```

Answer (score 2):

`VERSION` essentially is the name of a specific migration and not a point in time. You need to roll back multiple such “versions” to get back in time. These versions have the same names as the file names in `db/migrate` (without extension). This can be used to roll back a specific migration without undoing migrations done later.

Use the `STEP` parameter to go back in time a specified amount of migration steps.

Answer (score 2):

Migrations are timestamped. It is safe to assume that the latest timestamp is the current migration in most instances.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back

Comment: Great link - always needed  rake db:migrate:redo STEP=3